# How to solve Error of offset mismatch in Azure Databricks Autoloader cloudfiles source?

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

This happens when some files are deleted from the data source that Autoloader stream is reading from.

```py
try:
    raw_df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
            .option("cloudFiles.format","csv") \
            .option("cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles", "true") \
            .option("cloudFiles.allowOverwrites", "true") \
            .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", 
                opPath.outputPath +"/checkpoints/" + storageAccountInfo.adlsContainerName) \
            .option("delimiter","\t")\
            .load(source)

  except Exception as f:
    print(f)
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wfoY.png)

Comment: please post expanded stacktrace (click on `+` sign), especially the lines `Caused by:`

Answer (score 0):

I realized this was happening because some files were deleted from the blob storage which was the source of cloudfiles stream.